# How to add SQL-Server query hint in Hibernate Criteria API

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, criteria-api

we are using MS SQL-Server and Hibernate Criteria API.

Recently I discovered a query that suffers from parameter sniffing and so I would like to add a `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` as query hint. But although Hibernate seems to support [query hints for Criteria API](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2736) the added

```
criteria.addQueryHint("OPTION (RECOMPILE)");
```

does not seem to have any effect (the logged SQL does not contain any hints).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Hibernate Criteria API only supports query hints for Oracle databases.

The best solution I found was implementing the support for SQL-Server on my own (you could also do something like `criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("1=1 OPTION (RECOMPILE) "));` but that is pretty much a hack and does not work if you e.g. want to add an ordering to the query) .

I used the Hibernate implementation for Oracle as blueprint (have a look at `Oracle8iDialect`). For my use case it was sufficient to implement a version that appends the query hint to the end of the query (as the `OPTION`-clause is always at the end of the query).

```
package de.mystuff.hibernate;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.annotations.common.util.StringHelper;
import org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect;


/**
 * Special version of {@link SQLServer2008Dialect} which adds a simple query hint support.
 */
public class MySQLServer2012Dialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect {


    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * <p>
     * Currently this is a pretty simple query hint implementation. It just concatenates all SQL hints and adds them to the end of the query. This is fine for
     * e.g. {@code OPTION (RECOMPILE)}.
     */
    @Override
    public String getQueryHintString(String sql, List<String> hints) {
        if (hints.isEmpty()) {
            // no query hints at all
            return sql;
        }

        // concatenate all hints
        final String hint = StringHelper.join(", ", hints.iterator());

        if (StringHelper.isEmpty(hint)) {
            // all query hints are empty
            return sql;
        }

        return sql + " " + hint;
    }

}
```

Remind that you have to tell Hibernate to use your query hint supporting dialect:

```
hibernate.dialect=de.mystuff.hibernate.MySQLServer2012Dialect
```

Answer (score 2):

Hinting was added to the org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect class, so make sure the properties have `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect`

Using the javax.persistence.EntityManager:

```
var query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class);
query.addQueryHint("RECOMPILE");
return query.list();
```

The dialect will automatically prepend `OPTION`  to the argument.

Comment: If you just need to add addQueryHint to a javax.persistence.Query it seems you can just unwrap and add it and keep using the javax.persistence.Query

`Query query = em.createQuery(cq);
query.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class).addQueryHint("RECOMPILE");
return query.getResultList();`