# HQL and/or SQL Server a performance issue

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I have some difficulty understanding performance issues of Hibernate in conjunction with SQL Server.

My very sophisticated HQL Query with 16 joins and 41 parameters in the where clause looks something like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM Employee where Employee.age > 55
```

Before getting send to the SQL Server Hibernate translates it to SQL that looks like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select ... from employee e_1 where e_1.age > @P0',N'@P0 bigint',55
```

I don't know a lot about the internals of SQL Server, but as per my research `sp_executesql` is slow because it does not work with *execution plans* or was it because of *parameter sniffing*?

If it's intended to be slow, why does Hibernate use it, and how can I speed it up? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"per my research `sp_executesql` is slow because it does not work with _execution plans_ or was it because of parameter sniffing ?"* This statement is grossly wrong. *Parametrised* queries can result in parameter sniffing; that doesn't have anything to do with `sp_executesql`. As for execution plans, queries run by `sp_executesql` can be cached just like any other query.

Comment: I'm sorry, the documentation is quite overwhelming. Maybe I've got that wrong. The query that was generated takes up to 13 minutes. A version without the sp_executesql and without the parameters takes 20 seconds. Do you by any chance know, why this is?

Comment: Could be a lot of things, you'll need to compare the plans (and verify that the 13-minute version wasn't simply being blocked by some other process). But I assure you it's not because you used `sp_executesql`. How many rows in `Employee`? Is there an index on `Age`? Is age actually a `bigint` (and if so, why - `tinyint` should be sufficient unless we're talking about Yoda)? Does the index cover the other columns you obscured with `...`? 16 joins is a lot - I would say borderline ridiculous - and I would bet most of the 20 seconds is just compile time.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning "deeply mystified poster", thats the way I feel. I will definetly read it, although my problem is a little different. This query is slow in the application and in SSMS. Just modifications make it quicker.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I ruled out blocking by timing the query several times, even on different days. Employee.age does not even exist it's just an example from a domain that everybody can relate to. The biggest entity that is referenced by the query holds about 50.000 records. The resultset is expected to have 200 rows. As for the joins. I didn't design the database scheme. It is normalized though and I really do need columns from all 16 entities.

Comment: I'm not sure how timing it rules out blocking. Did you check `sys.dm_exec_requests` while it's running for 13 minutes and see if there's a value in `blocking_session_id` or what's present in the `*wait*` columns? Also I figured Age wasn't the thing but my questions about whether there's an index etc. apply no matter what that column is or how it's been obscured for us.

Comment: And again, _compare the plans_. We can't guess from an intentionally obscured and simplified SELECT statement. If one version of the query actually hard-codes `55` into the query, yes, SQL Server may treat that different than one with a parameter - in the latter case, it has to compile a plan that will work (and hopefully _well_) for _any_ parameter value - which could definitely lead to a different strategy, especially if there is a lot of skew.

Comment: Please share the query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan and please show us tables and index definitions

Answer (score 0):

When a query has parameters SQL Server chooses a query plan that will be reused for any parameter values.

When a query uses literals in the WHERE-clause SQL Server compiles a query for those specific parameter values.  Cases like `WHERE AGE>55` are likely to get a different plan than `WHERE AGE>@age`.

For literal values that are unlikely to change the plan, SQL may "autoparameterize" the query.  Typically that's for predicates like `WHERE ID = 1234` where the optimal plan really doesn't depend on the particular value.  The autoparameterized query can then be reused for other values.

You can force SQL Server to use the parameter values in optimizing the plan, at the cost of having to create a new plan for every query invocation with `OPTION RECOMPILE` query hint.

It looks like Hibernate supports this through the [addQueryHint](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#addQueryHint(java.lang.String)) API:   eg

[How to add SQL-Server query hint in Hibernate Criteria API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811247/how-to-add-sql-server-query-hint-in-hibernate-criteria-api)

Comment: added a bit on that.